# How to ignore keyboard safe area only for the last view in a VStack?

Tags: swiftui, vstack

The keyboard lifts the last view in a `VStack`.

[image: Banner ad lifted]

Adding `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` only to `BannerAd` doesn't work. (Why?)

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @FocusState var focusedId: ObjectId?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ItemsView(focusedId: $focusedId)
                BannerAd()
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        }
    }
}
```

If I add `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` to the `VStack`, the focus state doesn't work for the `ItemsView`. (correction: It just registered that the keyboard is simply lifting all views)

[image: ItemsView not working]

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

class Item: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String
}

struct ItemsView: View {
    @ObservedResults(Item.self) var items
    
    var focusedId: FocusState<ObjectId?>.Binding

    var body: some View {
        List {
            // Items
            ForEach(items) { item in
                ItemView(item: item, focusedId: focusedId)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: $items.remove)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Items")
        .toolbar {
            // Add
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    let item = Item()
                    $items.append(item)
                    focusedId.wrappedValue = item._id
                } label: {
                    Label("Add item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
            
            // Quick add
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                Button {
                    for i in 0...50 {
                        let item = Item()
                        item.name = "Item \(i)"
                        $items.append(item)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Add multiple items")
                }
            }
            
            // Delete
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button(role: .destructive){
                    $items.remove(atOffsets: IndexSet(integersIn: items.indices))
                } label: {
                    Label("Delete all", systemImage: "trash")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var item: Item
    
    var focusedId: FocusState<ObjectId?>.Binding
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Item", text: $item.name)
            .focused(focusedId, equals: item._id) // focus
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct BannerAd: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Banner ad")
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to ignore safe area only for `BannerAd`?